# Filter results using Jmespath on one dimensional array

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

Using jmespath and given the below json, how would I filter so only `JobNames` starting with "analytics" are returned?

For more context, the json was returned by the aws cli command `aws glue list-jobs`

```
{
    "JobNames": [
        "analytics-job1",
        "analytics-job2",
        "team2-job"
  ]
}
```

Tried this

```
JobNames[?starts_with(JobNames, `analytics`)]
```

but it failed with

> In function starts_with(), invalid type for value: None, expected one
> of: ['string'], received: "null"

Above I extracted the jmespath bit, but here is the entire aws cli command I tried and failed is this

```
aws glue list-jobs --query '{"as_string": to_string(JobNames[?starts_with(JobNames, `analytics`)])}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't test it on `list-jobs` but the query part works on `list-crawlers`. Just replaced the `JobNames` with `CrawlerNames`.

```
aws glue list-jobs --query 'JobNames[?starts_with(@, `analytics`) == `true`]'
```